# Executing code before the win32 loader?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have a VisualStudio unit test project - `Tests.exe`. This exe depends on dll projects `A` and `B` which produce `A.dll` and `B.dll` respectively.

When I execute `Tests.exe` it fails to run because `A` and `B` are not copied to the exe's output directory. I want to avoid doing this because there are 100's of exes and dlls.

Instead I would like some way to execute code before the Windows loader in order to call the `SetDllDirectory` API to add the directory that the `A` and `B` dll lives in.

So TL;DR - if an exe is missing a dll, how can I execute [`SetDllDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx) before the "N.dll is missing" error?

Comment: Put the executables all in the same folder and make life easy

Comment: Dlls would need to be there too, this is a huge 2000+ projects/many solutions etc. I really can't do that

Comment: Yes you can. If you don't then you need runtime linking.

Answer (score 0):

Use delay-loading. Technically, this doesn't answer your question - the Win32 loader will call your entry point only after it has loaded all DLL's that your executable imports. But with delay-loading, the compiler instead emits `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` calls that execute just-in-time. You can even customize the `LoadLibrary` calls and get the DLL `HMODULE` in any way you fancy.

Answer (score 0):

> [I]f an exe is missing a dll, how can I execute `SetDllDirectory` before the "N.dll is missing" error?

Basically you can't. That loader code executes before any user code, the are limitations to what you can try force into that code segment. You can push initialisation code "up" in the library section, but it still won't allow you to control where the dlls are loaded from.

**How to solve this then?**

*The easiest is to make sure the dlls and/or exe are built to (or copied to) the desired locations before executing the tests.*

Build solutions;

- VS allows you to mark dependent projects and then copies the dlls to the output folder - you can do this. Additionally if the projects are part of a single solution, set a common build output folder for each configuration.
- If the solution is not configured to include all the projects, you can add a "pre-build" step to copy the required dependencies to the output folder, or a "post-build" to copy the exe to a location that includes all the dependencies prior to the execution of the test exe. Alternatively, build to a common folder; defined either by convention or by a environment variable.

Runtime solutions;

- [Delay load the dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) after the paths have been fixed up. For each of the dlls to delay loading, add the [`/delayload` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx) to the command line;

  ```
  /DELAYLOAD:A.dll
  ```
- You can also directly use functions such as `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to control the loading of the dlls until later, you then have control over the location they are loaded from as well. This may require a "stub" of some sort to expose the dll functions as C compatible functions, so it may be far from ideal, but it is possible.

Comment: What about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx1x886y.aspx seems like delay loading could break things?

Comment: Yes, you will need to make sure that you are aware and code accordingly to those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things Visual Studio does not do well for C++ projects is produce "runnable" output.

The simplest way I've found to deal with this is to set a solution level output folder that all the binaries are built to. This ensures that all the EXEs and DLLs are in the same place, and any other assets they require can be deployed to the same folder.

tl;dr - Instead of copying the dlls to the unit test exe's folder - set the output path for the unit test to the dll's folder.